# Python precondition in function

Tags: python

I am beginner to python and i am trying to solve problem where i have to add precondition to solve the problem.

problem is mentioned like this
`The first parameter is a number of hours, the second parameter is a time in minutes (between 0 and 59, inclusive), and the third parameter is a time in seconds (between 0 and 59, inclusive). Return the combined time as a float value.`

```
def to_float_hours(hours, minutes, seconds):
    """ (int, int, int) -> float

    Return the total number of hours in the specified number
    of hours, minutes, and seconds.

    Precondition: 0 <= minutes < 60  and  0 <= seconds < 60

    >>> to_float_hours(0, 15, 0)
    0.25
    >>> to_float_hours(2, 45, 9)
    2.7525
    >>> to_float_hours(1, 0, 36)
    1.01
    """
    return (hours , minutes , seconds)
```

I am not sure how to implement precondition as mentioned in the problem, we have to solve problem without using print command in the function.

Comment: `if minutes < 0 or minutes >= 60: raise Exception(f'Invalid minutes {minutes}')`?

Comment: You can check with `if-else` statements and return `Exception`s for each of them.

Comment: ? generate syntax error

Answer (score 2):

You usually don't *need* to do anything about preconditions. They're a statement of what you expect to be done by those who call you (they should pass valid inputs). If you want to verify that you're getting what you expect, use one or more `assert` statements:

```
def to_float_hours(hours, minutes, seconds):
    # docstring omitted for brevity
    assert 0 <= minutes <= 60, "invalid value for minutes"
    assert 0 <= seconds <= 60, "invalid value for seconds"

    # do your stuff down here, without worrying about invalid inputs
```

If either of the preconditions are not met, this code will raise an exception if you're running in debug mode (the default). You can disable the assertion checking by running Python with the `-O` flag (which tells the interpreter to optimize for performance).

Answer (score 0):

how about returning 'invalid input' if precondition matched?

```
if (0 <= minutes < 60) or (0 <= seconds < 60):
    return 'invalid_input'
```

Comment: Rather than returning, raising a [ValueError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) for example would be a better idea, so the program exits with an error, or you can catch the error if there is a way to recover from it.

Comment: minutes between 0 and 60 and seconds between 0 and 60 is a valid condition.
So I believe the correct code should be `if not(0 <= minutes < 60) or not(0 <= seconds < 60): # raise error`

Answer (score 0):

The logic as below:

```py
def to_float_hours(hours, minutes, seconds):
    if minutes < 0 or minutes >= 60:
        return "Minutes parameter is not valid" # you can throw exception as well
    elif seconds < 0 or seconds >= 60:
        return "Seconds parameter is not valied" # you can throw exception as well

    # Rest of the code
```